# Parsing HTML with XPath following Categories

Tags: c#, html, parsing, xpath

I have the following HTML structure, each tr tag is separated with each other, so when i tried to parse with XPATH, it is supposed to have 2 subitems for just one category, but with my code below it selects all 4 subitems into 1 category, so each category has 4 subitems instead of just 2.

```
<table class="available">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td class="catname" colspan="2">
            <span>Category 1</span>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td rowspan="2" colspan="1" class="itemdetail">
            <div class="subname">
               SubItem1-1
            </div>
         </td>
         <td class="precioseleccion desgloseth">
            <div class="preprice">
               <strong class="price">39.99 €</strong>
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td rowspan="2" colspan="1" class="itemdetail">
            <div class="subname">
               SubItem1-2
            </div>
         </td>
         <td class="precioseleccion desgloseth">
            <div class="preprice">
               <strong class="price">49.99 €</strong>
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="catname" colspan="2">
            <span>Category 2</span>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td rowspan="2" colspan="1" class="itemdetail">
            <div class="subname">
               SubItem2-1
            </div>
         </td>
         <td class="precioseleccion desgloseth">
            <div class="preprice">
               <strong class="price">59.99 €</strong>
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td rowspan="2" colspan="1" class="itemdetail">
            <div class="subname">
               SubItem2-2
            </div>
         </td>
         <td class="precioseleccion desgloseth">
            <div class="tooltip3">
               <strong class="price">69.99 €</strong>
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>    
</table>
```

> ```
> var doc = new HtmlDocument(); // with HTML Agility pack
>             doc.LoadHtml(uricontent);
>
>             var rooms = doc.DocumentNode
>            .SelectNodes("//table[@class='available']//td[@class='catname']")
>            .Select(r => new
>            {
>                Type= r.InnerText.CleanInnerText(),
>
>                SubTypes= r.SelectNodes("../..//tr//td[@class='itemdetail']//div[@class='subname']")
>
>                             .Select(s => new
>                             {
>                                 SubType= s.InnerText.CleanInnerText(),
>                                 Price =  
>                                     s.SelectSingleNode(".//parent::td/following-sibling::td[@class='allprice']//div[@class='preprice']//strong[@class='price']")
>                                         .InnerText.CleanInnerText()
>                             }).ToArray()
>
>            }).ToArray();
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, to select all the Categories you want `//tr[td[@class='catname']]`, and to select their sub-items you want `following-sibling::tr/td[div[@class='subname']]`.